# Can't upload expo react native app to github repo: "Updating file content failed. EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory .read"

Tags: react-native, expo, gitkraken

Following is my error

[image]

I have an entire expo react native app inside /mobile folder, but i can't push it.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the presence of other .git folders in the added project was causing the problem:

1. Check if you have any *.git* folders in the added project folder.
2. If they are present, remove all of them, but **NOT** the one in your main folder.
3. Restart GitKraken.